# Understanding of threshold value in a neural network

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

Consider the hypothetical neural network [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTjEs.jpg)

$o_1$ is the output of neuron 1.
$o_2$ is the output of neuron 2.
$w_1$ is the weight of connection between 1 and 3.
$w_2$ is the weight of connection between 2 and 3.
So the input to neuron 3 is $i =o_1w_1 +o_2w_2$
Let the activation function of neuron 3 be sigmoid function.
$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ and the threshold value of neuron 3 be $\theta$.
Therefore, output of neuron 3 will be $f(i)$ if $i\geq\theta$ and $0$ if $i\lt\theta$.
Am I correct?

Comment: 1 if crossing the threshold, 0 if not.

(Sometimes you can see 1 in the literature if it exceeds the threshold, -1 if it does not)